# Indexed float array in NASM x86 16-bit

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm, 16-bit

I'm trying to fill an array of double-precision (64-bit) real numbers using the loop instructions in NASM x86 16-bit, but I get the `invalid effective address` error. The OS is Windows XP 32 bits, but the program actually runs as a MS-DOS 16-bit one.

For example:

```
    mov cx, 10
fill_array:
    fld qword[yArray + cx*8]
    fstp qword[xArray + cx*8]
    loop fill_array
```

Returns the previous error at the `fld` and `fstp` lines.

The arrays are declared this way:

```
yArray resq 10
xArray resq 10
```

I've also tried using a register as a pointer to the array, but, for example, `fstp qword[ax]` also fails.

Is there a way to use indexed float arrays in 16-bit assembly? Do I need to use any particular FPU instructions?

Comment: There's no scaling in 16bit addressing. And also no addressing with `cx`.

Comment: @harold Thanks. So, is the only solution hardcoding the addressing (`fld qword[yArray + 8]`) and repeating it N times?

Comment: Oh no, there are solutions.. you could use `ecx` (should generate address size override), or you could use any of the 16bit addressing things listed [here](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm16.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CPUs >= 386 you can use scaling even in 16-bit mode, but only with 32-bit registers:

```
    mov ecx, 10
fill_array:
    fld qword[yArray + ecx*8]
    fstp qword[xArray + ecx*8]
    loop fill_array
```

But you have an "off-by-one error". If ECX=10 you address the **eleventh** element of the list and ECX=0 will end the loop i.e. it won't be processed. You can avoid that with a "hand-made" loop:

```
    mov ecx, 9
fill_array:
    fld qword[yArray + ecx*8]
    fstp qword[xArray + ecx*8]
    sub cx, 1
    jnc fill_array
```

The "pure 8086" solution:

```
    mov cx, 10
    mov bx, 0
fill_array:
    fld qword[yArray + bx]
    fstp qword[xArray + bx]
    add bx, 8
    loop fill_array
```